# inject $rootScope in config angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have problem to inject $rootScope in config angularJS, this is my code, but still error, maybe anyone help me how to inject $rootScope in config angularJS. .

thanks.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('uliappApp')
    .directive('angular-loading-bar', ['cfpLoadingBarProvider'])
    .config(cfpLoadingBarProvider);

  cfpLoadingBarProvider.$inject = ['cfpLoadingBarProvider', '$rootScope'];

  function cfpLoadingBarProvider(cfpLoadingBarProvider, $rootScope) {
    cfpLoadingBarProvider.includeBackdrop = true;
    console.log(rootScope.concessionLoadingScreen);
    cfpLoadingBarProvider.spinnerTemplate = '<div class="loading-bar-container">'
        + '<div id="loading-bar-spinner"><div class="spinner-icon"></div></div></div>';
  }
})();
```

Comment: Why do you need `rootScope` in configuration phase? I don't think you can do that

Comment: I want to take value in variable $rootScope.concessionLoadingScreen from other controller from create conditions. .may be you can give me tips for that..@sat

Answer (score 9):

You don't need `rootScope` in configuration phase, it can be simply achieved by using `.run()`.

```
angular
    .module('uliappApp')
    .run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
        $rootScope.concessionLoadingScreen = true;
    }])
```

Comment: why in my console.log($rootScope.concessionLoadingScreen) still undefined. .? @satpal

Comment: I want to send $urlRouterProvider.otherwise route with checking params in  rootscope

Answer (score 2):

During the config phase, only providers can be injected.

Basically angularjs first invoke the config method and then invoke the run method. During config only providers are available. A provider can then be used to create service instance. **So, you can use `.run` to inject `$rootScope`.**

For example, the following is not allowed:

```
myMod.config(function(greeting) {
  // WON'T WORK -- greeting is an *instance* of a service.
  // Only providers for services can be injected in config blocks.
});
```

What you do have access to are any providers for services you've made:

```
myMod.config(function(greetingProvider) {
  // ok fine!
});
```

All the best.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `$rootScope` during the configuration phase of an angular application.

Only `constant` and `provider` can be injected to the configuration phase.

You can use `run` phase, or create a `provider` (that is actually a service) to hold the configuration you want.

```
// Option 1 - during run
angular
    .module('yourApp')
    .run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    }])

// Option 2 - provider
angular
    .module('yourApp')
    .provider('yourSettings', function() {
        var $this = this;

        this.yourSettings = 'yourValue';

        this.$get = function() {
            return $this;
        }
    })
angular
    .module('yourApp')
    .config(['yourSettingsProvider', function(yourSettingsProvider) {
        // You can use yourSettingsProvider.yourSettings 
    }])
```